# Qt Creator force_debug_info and seperate_debug_info build options

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator, qmake

My understanding is, in this case, symbols are generated in a separate file. I was wondering what is the extension of the files generated?Is it a .debug? and what folder the files generated exist? I don't see any file being generated.

Little bit of context: I am planning on playing back the coredump generated using GDB debugger. For this, I am thinking, I need the exe/bin(without symbols)and then the separate symbol file, and of course the .core file. I don't want to use CONFIG=debug since that will make my exe/bin too large.